# Switching logic on net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have third-party-supplied code that interacts between software installed on the user's machine and my cloud application. With the upgrade in Chrome's security enforcement, old versions of the native software are giving me `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` when the browser attempts to communicate with it. This error is resolved with the user upgrading their native software.

However, I would like to be able to catch the error in the browser and use that to tell the user to upgrade their native software. I cannot for the life of me find a way to catch that error. `try...catch` doesn't work, `window.addEventListener('error')` doesn't work, nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: does `try{...}catch(e){ console.log(e); }` log anything?

Comment: @TomaszRadwaski nope. Of course it wouldn't because it's an asynchronous call, but it also doesn't if I force `$.get` to be synchronous.